# How can I see where my program crashes in a given file?

Tags: c++, debugging

My problem is that when I debug my modification on a c++ project (it is very huge) and when the program crashes, the visual studio shows me another cpp file where the program crashes. I know it shows me that because it is related to it, but I need the root where the crash started to I can fix my code. I have tried doing "step out" SHIFT + F11, not worked. So how can I make the debugger strict to my file ?

I know this question is gonna be underrated, but I can only explain this way.

Comment: have you tried lookign at the call stack?

Comment: Oh thanks ! I never heard of it.